# What is the best programming language and regression method for this private equity investment dataset?

Tags: r, regression, python

The excel (can be csv) dataset I want to work with has thousands of company names, and for each company, a few rounds of investment. This means many mentions of the same company but with different numbers over time. As a fake example with incorrect numbers:

(Company name, round name, round number, investment amount, post-investment valuation, date)

- Facebook, Seed, 1, $5,000,000, $20,000,000, 01-01-05
- Facebook, Series A, 2, $10,000,000, $50,000,000, 05-11-07
- AirBnB, Seed, 1, $200,000, $5,000,000, 10-08-10

and so on...

Usually each company has a single-digit amount of rounds (1-7 for the majority). There are many other columns that I also have more gathered info on each company, such as investors, amount raised to date, and debt round. I also have some derived columns from the given info, such as change in value from previous round, change in amount raised from previous round, normalized value (given an equation I developed), and other derived yes/no columns.

What I would like to do is be able to use all of these variables to make predictions for:

1. Next round post-investment valuation
2. Next round amount raised
3. Next round deal date
4. Whether a company fits a high-growth company identification model (to be created)

Answer (score 1):

On the one hand, the data have panel format. They have two dimensions: company & time. Therefore, the ideas of classic panel data approaches, like [mixed effects models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixed_model), would be helpful here... Stata and R are the best packages for panel data.

On the other hand, if the data have 10,000+ companies (better 100,000+ companies) you can employ non-linear and non-parametric methods of machine learning: [gradient boosting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient_boosting), [random forest](http://www.stanfordphd.com/RandomForest.html), [support vector machine](http://www.stanfordphd.com/SVM.html), etc. Arguably, R is the best language for that.

All in all, you may benefit from combining the panel data and machine learning approaches. So R wins.